# What does number + "e+4" mean in javascript

Tags: javascript, math

I have a code snippet with the following declaration:

```
const x = x + "e+4"
```

I dont understand what the "e+4" is and/or does.

Comment: It’s literally the string that contains `e+4`. It has no special meaning on its own. Is this supposed to be parsed as a Number, i.e. is `x` used like `Number("1e+4")`? Have you read the [documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#exponential)? See ['e' in javascript numbers](/q/39423555/4642212).

Answer (score 0):

This is a scientific notation.

`e+4` is the same as writting `* 10 ^ (+4)`

Comment: Might as well write it explicitly 10000 (ten thousand)